# Find parent or parents directories of a file

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a file say xyz.doc .I want to find the parent /Parents of this file ,so that i can bind it in a tree view . How can we achive this ?

I have the fileinfo class which is obtained by  the code

```
FileInfo[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path,"*.*);
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly? You have a 'path' variable, which is the parent.

Comment: So this is the parent you look for. No?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
LookingFor(new FileInfo(path).Directory));

public void LookingFor(DirectoryInfo dir)
{
   if (dir.Parent == null)
      return;
   // Add parent to ListView
   LookingFor(dir.Parent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take the path of the directory, and call the `GetParent` method.  You can do this in a loop if need be and walk back up the directory tree:

```
string parentDir = Directory.GetParent("some path");
```